# Enabling ethernet over USB support in Linux kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

How to enable Ethernet over USB support in Linux kernel?

Which driver (like `CONFIG_USB_USBNET`) is related to this support?

Is EEM (Ethernet Emulation) regarding this support or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `CONFIG_USB_USBNET` together with whatever `CONFIG_USB_NET_*` module you need for your USB device.

The only thing I can find in my config that could match your EEM is `CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_EEM` but I don't have that enabled, that is another USB device that I don't own.

Comment: Your answer is very useful only for understanding about this clearly. But I want exact name like `CONFIG_USB_USBNET` for this Ethernet over USB support.

Comment: As I said, you need at least `CONFIG_USB_USBNET` and a device-specific module. If you enable all `CONFIG_USB_NET_*` als modules then your device should probably work. To be clear: there are many different USB network adapters, and hence many different kernel modules to support them. It might even be that your device isn't supported by Linux. I can't get any more "exact" than this.